# Change Calculate percentage in my selection list

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have an invoice calculator and i need that the Total Amount of my Invoice change on the different selection of the IVA percentage that i want to apply.

This is my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Manna/cpRa2/7/) , as you can see i have created a select editable if you click on IVA 21% you get 2 option: Iva 21% or NO IVA. Now the total amount is calculated on 21% of IVA.
How can i make my total amount no calculating the 21% when i select none?

This is my editable select

```
$('.editable_selectiva').editable(function(value, settings) { 
             console.log(this);
             console.log(value);
             console.log(settings);
             return(value);
          }, {
               data   : "{'IVA 21%':'IVA 21%','NO IVA':'NO IVA'}", 
             type    : 'select',
             style  : "inherit",
         });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have partially solved your problem. I just changed the method tally a bit:

```
function tally(selector) {
    var total = 0;
    $('p.editable_number').each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).text()) || 0;
        $('#subtotal').html(total);
        if ($('.editable_selectiva').text() === "NO IVA") {
            $('#total').html(0);
            $('#total1').html(total);
        }
        else {
            $('#total').html(total*0.21);
            $('#total1').html(total*1.21);
        }
    })
}
```

Although it is not the cleaniest method it works (try changing to "NO IVA" and then adding a new product and you will see that it works). **The only thing you need to do now is to somehow execute the tally method when the user changes the selctor from "IVA 21" to "NO IVA"**.

Advice: Consider using Backbonejs MVC framework to build javascript aplications. It provides great tools for event handling and allows front-end developers to build cleaner web applications in Javascript.

Comment: it works and i am trying that the event happen when the No IVA is selected. This is the code i am trying to use:  $('.editable_selectiva').text() === "NO IVA").change(function() {
              $('#total').html(0.21);
              $('#total1').html(total);
 }); what do u think? many thanks

Comment: In my opinion, what you should do to trigger the event is to add an "onSubmit" function when calling editable in $('.editable_selectiva').editable(...)

I guess you are using the editable jQuery plugin, so try looking at the documentation at http://www.arashkarimzadeh.com/jquery/7-editable-jquery-plugin.html